# Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed (done - 0.0.2.0:2)

Tags: error, meek

i am using meek amazon transport with https proxy type but unable to connect to tor browser below are the logs

```
20/01/2017 13:38:59 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
20/01/2017 13:40:14 PM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
20/01/2017 13:40:14 PM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
20/01/2017 13:40:14 PM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
20/01/2017 13:40:14 PM.900 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
20/01/2017 13:40:20 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
20/01/2017 13:40:20 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
20/01/2017 13:40:20 PM.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn; host B9E7141C594AF25699E0079C1F0146F409495296 at 0.0.2.0:2) 
20/01/2017 13:40:20 PM.800 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
20/01/2017 13:40:20 PM.800 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
20/01/2017 13:40:22 PM.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
20/01/2017 13:40:22 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
20/01/2017 13:40:22 PM.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another Meek transport bridge, try meek-azure or maybe you should run it on VPS yourself - it seems that your proxy is intercepting and banning connections.

Comment: Thanks for the answer alexey the azure transport bridge is also not working.....if proxy is banning the connection what alternatives i can use..?? i tried psiphon but that also not useful.....

Comment: what kind of proxy it is? can you open just a strict list of a websites through it?

Comment: yes it opens just a strict list of a websites......

Comment: do you have a list of these websites? If none of them using azure or amazon cloudfront - I'm afraid it won't be possible to access Tor through it, because it uses strict list checking, especially if it's a HTTPS CONNECT proxy